# Apache Camel XSLT

Tags: xslt, apache-camel

I am new to XSLT, trying to create an endpoint using XSLT.
I know how to call xsl file from particular directory. My question is how to add the xsl file within the camel route and can use it in xslt endpoint.
I tried writing XSL thing within javascript in camel route like ,

```
<script>
<javascript>
    ...xsl code goes here
</javascript>
</script>
```

While doing this getting error "org.apache.camel.builder.script.ScriptEvaluationException - Failed to evaluate: js". Is there any other way to set in header or body.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Camel has a XSLT component which you can use:

```
<to uri="xslt:myXslFile.xsl" />
```

You can read more about this component in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/xslt.html).

Comment: Thank for ur comment. Instead of using external file like .xsl I need to write complete set of xsl code within route itself and need to be used in <to uri="xslt:...">

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Camel Docs](http://camel.apache.org/xslt.html):

> To provide a dynamic stylesheet at runtime you can define a dynamic URI. See [How to use a dynamic URI in to()](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) for more information.

I guess (did not tried it) it could be something like `<toD uri="xsl:${header.foo}"/>` to load the stylesheet from the header named `foo`. The `toD` is to route to a dynamic endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your spring dsl route

```
 <camel:to uri="xslt:YourXSLFile.xsl" />
```